# Keep program running in background ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, application-state

I am working on an application which allows to send messages to another user.

If I press Home Button app goes first in background and then in suspended state so I don't receive any message unless I bring app back to the foreground.

How can I fix this to receive messages even if app is in background or suspended state? Solution is to avoid app to go suspended?

Some ideas please

Thanks and regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)

Comment: @AntonyRaphel his question is related to when the app doesn't receive notifications in the background not foreground. Thanks!

Comment: Use push notifications. You'll need a server for that i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to use Push notifications as they will wake your app when a notification is received (in your case a message is sent to your app). Do you have this implemented?

Another Dirty way would be to keep a silent Music file playing when in background state thus the app nevel sleeps (unless terminated by user). Nut keep in mind that this trick wont let you publish your app to the app store!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will push notifications work if the sender is Android device? or even PC?

Comment: Yes, however to use Push notifications you need a developer account (99$ per year) even in development stage.

Comment: And also I need to tell my server to send the message to Apple's APNS server otherwise I won't get notified, right?

Comment: Yes, and you can program your android to do that, however I need to ask, are you trying to do notifications between devices and not mainly from servers? fir that Firebase is a perfect tool to achieve what you are doing

Comment: No, I have my own server and messages go through it, so I guess I would need to change also clients in other platforms

Comment: yes, if you feel this is the right answer I kindly ask you to mak it as correct :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Voip to wake the app upon receiving push notification then handle it and pull from server as you want

[migrate-to-ios-voip-push-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039951/migrate-to-ios-voip-push-notifications)

Comment: Just by adding that will the app "wake up" from time to time?

Comment: This for temporary fetch I will edit it for time to time